# Motivation for the fractional Sobolev spaces

Tags: sobolev-spaces, motivation, parabolic-pde, fractional-sobolev-spaces

I am strying studying on my own parabolic PDEs throughout the book "Linear and Quasi-linear Equations of Parabolic Type" by  Vsevolod A. Solonnikov, Nina Uraltseva, Olga Ladyzhenskaya, but there is one thing that I do not understand: why we are looking for the solutions of linear and quasi-linear parabolic PDEs in fractional Sobolev spaces instead of the classical Sobolev spaces. I believe that there is some problem that we find when we try looking for these solutions in the classical Sobolev spaces, but I could not realize what is this problem and the only thing that I could find about the motivation for fractional Sobolev spaces is [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3222860/fractional-sobolev-spaces-and-trace-theory). I will be grateful if someone can explain why we work in fractional Sobolev spaces instead of the classical Sobolev spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer is that  you can find better and sharper estimates using fractional spaces, or interpolation spaces. Let me give an example, our favorite parabolic pde:
\begin{align}
u_t=u_{xx}. 
\end{align}
When we denote by $S(t)$ the semigroup generated by the laplacian, we can solve the equation as
\begin{align}
u(t)=S(t)u_0.
\end{align}
Suppose we want to measure $u(t)$ in some Hilbert space $X$, and the initial condition is from a space $Y$, then we find
\begin{align}
||u(t)||_X\leq ||S(t)||_{L(Y,X)}||u_0||_Y.
\end{align}
The key question is now how the operator norm depends on time. For $X=H^2$ and $Y=L^2$, we know that the operator norm has a singularity of $t^{-1}$, but when we take $Y=H^2$ there is no singularity. Now what if we take an initial condition that is smoother then $L^2$, but not as smooth as $H^2$? How strong will the singularity be? In order to answer these questions, you need interpolation spaces between $H^2$ and $L^2$, in other words, you want to construct a family of spaces $H^\alpha$ in between $H^2$ and $L^2$, and fractional Sobolev spaces are a nice explicit way to construct these spaces. I do recommend to study these lecture notes, http://people.dmi.unipr.it/alessandra.lunardi/. Corollary 4.1.11 is the famous Ladyzhenskaja – Solonnikov – Ural’ceva-theorem, and the use of interpolation spaces becomes very clear here.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but is there other link for this lecture notes? The link is broken.

Comment: Mmm, strange, well, you could always google `lunardi Analytic Semigroups and Reaction-Diffusion Problems'

Comment: thanks for the reference! One thing that is not well clear for me: what you mean by 'singularity'? I only know the definition for kinds of singularities given in a course of Complex Analysis. Is your definition of singularity for semigroup some of these definitions? I looked for this definition in some book of Analytic Semigroups, including in Lunardi's book, but I did not find

Comment: By singularity I simply mean `divide by zero', just as in complex analysis. Hence, the operator norm above from $H^2$ to $L^2$, which goes as $t^{-1}$, has a singularity of order 1 at $t=0$.

Comment: thanks for the clarification! If you know the answer, can you answer my question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/355396/regularity-theory-for-parabolic-pdes-in-fractional-sobolev-spaces) please?