# Reference recommendation for sobolev space on the unit sphere

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, sobolev-spaces, book-recommendation, fractional-sobolev-spaces

Sobolev space on the unit sphere is usually defined with the help of spherical harmonics, but is there any reference where the equivalence to the classical fractional sobolev space definition is shown? And preferably also the construction of the classical fractional sobolev space.
I would greatly appreciate it, thanks.

Comment: I suppose that would be defined as the restriction (in the sense of trace) of the appropriate sobolev space to the sphere

Comment: @CalvinKhor could you please elaborate, I'm only familiar with the normal definition of sobolev space and the one using spherical harmonics. It would be great if you could also give a reference recommendation, I only need to see that they are both equivalent in order to use the product rules (and composition) since they aren't usually proven using the spherical harmonics definition, thanks!

Comment: Perhaps check this Math.SE question [Fractional Sobolev Spaces and Trace Theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3222860/fractional-sobolev-spaces-and-trace-theory) ? Hope it helps

Comment: @CalvinKhor Thank you!